# PHP group by similar value called by function

Tags: php, loops, foreach, grouping

I have an element with title, type, description and so on. I have a DAO that defines all that and functions already created that extract the type for one element only: it's getById().

How can I loop through all the elements and create groups of them by the same id?

```
$group = array();
foreach ($announcement as $announcements) {
    $announcementType = $this->getById($this->typeId());
}
```

I should put an "if" here, but I cannot understand how to "create a group for each elements with the same typeId".

Comment: Can you clarify your question, the intended result and explain what you mean by `group`? The above simply overwrites the `$announcementType` and does nothing else - we have no context as to how that variable might be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you cycle over $announcements, anyway you can try a solution like this:

```
$group = [];

foreach ($announcements as $announcement) {
   $id = $this->typeId();
   $group[$id][] = $this->getById($id);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, it's a complicated process and it's difficult to explain it without being too long. I think that this solution might work with some adjustments. I'll use it!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php) (is not an common answer but still an answer):

```
//Considering every announcement has an id


$callback = function($prevResult, $item) { 
    $id = $item->typeId();
    $prevResult[$id][] = $this->getById($id);
    return $prevResult;
};

$groupedById = array_reduce($announcements, $callback, []);
//empty array as last parameter if the announcements 
//array is empty os the return type still the same
```